# Can't retrieve formData sent through AJAX to insert new wordpress post, PHP sees values as blank

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm sending formData through jQuery.ajax(), however the PHP function that is processing all this can't properly retrieve and recognize the DATA being sent. I've went through many questions on stackoverflow and also tried this in many different ways all to no avail and finally gave up.

This is all done in WORDPRESS.

I *can't* use serialize because I'm also sending files, but I left them out below for the sake of simplicity.

This is the simplified version of the form:

```
<form id="newForm" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <div>
        <label>Title</label>
        <input name="title" type="text" value=""/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Content</label>
        <input name="content" type="text" value=""/>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" id="submit_button">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

This is the jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
$('#newForm').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var new_data = new FormData($(this)[0]);                      
    $.ajax({
        url:ajaxurl,
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            'action': 'upload_function',
            new_data //I've tried new_data: new_data
        },
        cache:false,
        processData:false,
        dataType: 'json', //tried not sending it as json dataType, still didn't work
        success:function(response){
            console.log(response);
            if(response.success == 1){
            alert("Post inserted");
            }else{
            alert("Post not inserted");
            }
        },
        error:function(){
            alert("Ajax request hasn't passed");
        }
    });
   });
});
```

This is the PHP that handles the post insert(it's getting called properly, I've checked by inserting static values in post title and content), I left out the nonce and other stuff for the sake of simplicity:

```
function upload_function(){
        $json_result=array();
        $json_input=$_POST['new_data'];
        $post_vars=json_decode($json_input,true);
        $submit_post_data = array (
            'post_title' => $post_vars['title'],
            'post_content' => $post_vars['content'],
            'post_status' => 'draft'
        );
        $post_id = wp_insert_post($submit_post_data);
        if($post_id){
            $json_result['success']=1;
        }else{
            $json_result['success']=0;
        }
        wp_send_json($json_result);
        exit();
    }
add_action('wp_ajax_upload_function','upload_function');
```

Comment: `new FormData($(this)[0]);` here $(this)[0] will return the form element. You cannot pass it.. You must pass the form data inside the form

Comment: Exactly, you pass the form element with [0] as the argument to FormData, that's how it works and how others do it. I believe the reason this isn't working is something else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to serialize the form data and then pass it to the php code. Do this to your `var new_data` assignment.

```
var new_data = $(this).serialize()
```

**EDIT 1:** As you stated you have files you need use FormData object to pass the files to sever in ajax. refer the code below.

```
var $element = $(this);
var formdata = new FormData();
var totalFiles = $element.files.length;    

if (totalFiles > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < totalFiles; i++) {
        var file = $element.files[i];

        formdata.append("FileUpload", file);
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: Url,
        data: formdata,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (result) {
            // make the server return a array of file names that has been saved.
            //Post your other form elements data a this point with the filename array.
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log("File Upload Failure");
        }
    });       
}
```

Comment: I already wrote in the question, that I can't use serialize because I have files in the form, and they won't get passed. Also btw. when trying it with serialize before I still couldn't retrieve the values passed, they vere blank.

Comment: sorry I missed out that part, You have to do a wrok around to post files in ajax. Its not straight forward.

Comment: Why don't I upload both the files and the other elements together at once? And how do I post other formdata on success? Call a jQuery function with another ajax call in it?

Comment: i never tried uploading both. you can give a try. And yes I meant another ajax call

Comment: if you have only few input items then you can extract each value and send the whole thing as a object.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have a ton... and I don't know how to send the checkbox array this way. Could you just write up 1 example?

Comment: Can't we serilaze the form now ?? Since now you posted all the files by Ajax we are now only left with input items without files. We can try the serilaze approach right... But you need to remove the file input elements and then serilaze

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104727/discussion-between-brodev-and-reddy).